# flow type error on type State and type Props

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, flow-typed

I am using flow, and mostly things are working out, but I am catching this error in my linting on something as trivial as this:

```
 type Props = {
  actions: object,
  products: object,
 };

 type State = {
   email: string,
   name: string
 };

 class SomeComponent extends Component {
  // etc..
 }
```

The linting errors show right after the "type" keyword and the error is:

**"Expecting newline or semicolon"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 possibilities that I see here:

1) `object` should be capitalized (`Object`)

2) You are not using `eslint-plugin-flowtype`

Comment: you sure it should be "Object", I thought object, string, boolean are acceptable and preferred. No?

Comment: 100% sure. To be even more specific, it's recommended that you use [sealed object types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/) and not plain Objects, because almost any variable in JavaScript inherits from Object. You can try it for yourself [here](https://flow.org/try/): Attempting to use lowercase `object` will throw the exception `identifier `object`. Could not resolve name`. Note that lowercase `string` and `boolean` are indeed preferred.

Comment: hmm, interesting. I am not catching any errors with lowercase, so I never noticed. Interesting.. thanks for the info. I will turn my object in Object! :-)

Answer (score 0):

This may seem silly, but I had to go into IntelliJ IDEA -> Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript and change `JavaScript language version` to `Flow` (was previously `React JSX`). I was already using `eslint-plugin-flowtype`, and was wondering why it was not working.